# Connection was not closed. Connection's current state is open

Tags: c#, connection

It gives the error connection was not closed. Connection's current state is open.
Please help out with the code.

```
  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\vicky\Desktop\Gym management system\Fitness_club\vicky.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM [plan] where plantype='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", con);

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string amount = dr.GetString(1);
                textBox5.Text = amount;

            }
            con.Close();
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

}
```

Comment: which line does the error occur?

Comment: it doesn't shows any line of the error, i tried putting the con.Close(); inside the finally block and i still get the same error.

Comment: Remove the try/catch to see where it fails, or simply go step by step

Comment: When you run the code in the debugger, there will be a line that it barfs on.

Comment: it still doesnt show any line of error after removing the try catch block. its really weird

Comment: Are you starting your application from Visual Studio with debug?

Comment: yes, it just shows a popup for Connection was not closed. Connection's current state is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `using` blocks to help with managing your objects.

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connStr = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\vicky\Desktop\Gym management system\Fitness_club\vicky.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        string cmdText = "Select * FROM [plan] where plantype=@planType";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = cmdText;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@planType", comboBox1.Text);

            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                string amount = reader.GetString(1);
                textbox5.Text = amount;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also note the use of parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks. Since you are probably only expecting one value to be returned, you should specify the name of the column in the query and use `ExecuteScalar` instead of the reader and the `while` loop. The other alternative is to use `CommandBehavior.SingleRow` as the parameter to the command, which tells the command to just return a single row result.

You also have a cross-threading problem here, and you can solve it by using some invoking.

```
string amount = string.Empty;
if (reader.Read())
{
    amount = reader.GetString(1);
}
if (this.InvokeRequired)
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { textbox5.Text = amount; });
else
    textbox5.Text = amount;
```

Another thing to note, is to give your controls meaningful names. Its a **lot** easier to debug or understand a control named `cbx_PlanType` than `combobox1`, or `tbx_PlanAmount` rather than `textbox5`.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me through this but i'm still getting the same error. I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: Are you using an SQL-Server connection in other places that you are not closing?

Comment: Thanks i solved it now. It was open in another class.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\vicky\Desktop\Gym management system\Fitness_club\vicky.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM [plan] where plantype='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", con);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string amount = dr.GetString(1);
            textBox5.Text = amount;

        }
        // check if connection is open
        if (con.State == 1)
            con.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // check if connection is open
        if (con.State == 1)
            con.Close();
    }
}
```